# Why <a> tag replaces spaces with %2520? how to solve the issue?

Tags: javascript, html, url

In this case, I suppose explaining the problem as a scenario would be the best way to explain it.

I have a search box in a page called `A.html`, parameters that are passed to this page should be replaced with the value of its search box. The problem is that, when I pass the parameters the spaces get replaced by `%2520` therefore wrong value will be added to the search box. I need to solve it.

1. `<a href="www.example.com/a.html?value=Here and there">Link</a>`
2. Following address will be put into the address bar: `www.example.com/a.html?value=Here%2520and%2520there`
3. This value will be replaced with the value of the search box: `Here%2520and%2520there`.  I need to have this value `"Here and There"` in my search box. (without `%2520`)

Comment: Because that is a properly encoded url. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: you can't have spaces in an url

Answer (score 5):

What seems to have happened here is that the URL was double encoded (see below); while I can't explain exactly why that happens, it may be because your URL is not properly URL encoded:

```
<a href="www.example.com/a.html?value=Here and there">Link</a>
```

It should be:

```
<a href="www.example.com/a.html?value=Here+and+there">Link</a>
```

Or:

```
<a href="www.example.com/a.html?value=Here%20and%20there">Link</a>
```

Double encoding goes like this:

```
" "      regular space
"%20"    percent encoded, " " -> "%20"
"%2520"  percent encoded, "%" -> "%25"
```

#### Update

The reason I couldn't explain the double encoding is because the question was missing exactly how the passed value was added to the search box. The most likely scenario is that the search box is populated with a percent encoded value. To fix that, you have to decode the value first, i.e.

```
searchBox.value = decodeURIComponent('Here%20and%20there');
```

See also: [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: @Jack I don't see any search box in your question; perhaps you could clear that up for me?

Comment: I explained in the question that whatever the value of the "value" parameter is would be placed into search box of the page. Therefore, if I pass the address with "Here+and+there" then the value of the seasrch box would also become "Here+and+there" which I do not want.

Comment: @Jack Let me rephrase that; *how* are you passing the value into the search box?

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, serving this data as a URL requires spaces and other non-ascii characters to be URL encoded. Without this, the browser would not be able to properly parse the URI.

You can make changes to solicit the raw data without encoding it (keep spaces intact), but this will be of no use if you are appending to a URL. If you aren't, feel free to paste the code relating to whatever you are trying to do with the data.